# Bullet Physics - cutting a hole in the geometry

Tags: collision-detection, physics, bulletphysics

I have a static rigid body created with `btBvhTriangleMeshShape`. This rigid body will be a room.

Now I'm making a portal (teleport) on the floor. Due to this portal there should be a hole in the geometry of the static object. I dont know if it is possible in `Bullet` to making something like that (without creating whole rigid body again), but all what I want is, that the other dynamic objects should interract with this "hole", as if it there really was.

Is there a way to do that? Do I have to do something with collision groups/masks? Is it even possible with this physics library?

Comment: Since you are using a triangular mesh, why don't you just remove triangles from where the hole should be? You might need to add a few more vertices around the hole as well.

Comment: Yes I know, I was thinking to do that with existing shape of the rigid body, but you can't... you have to build whole rogid body again and that might be slow, i think

Answer (score 1):

In this case i would make the room with the hole from the start, and if I understood correctly when the portal is opened the hole appears. You have an object that covers the hole and when the portal opens, you remove this object and the hole can be trespassed by other objects.
This way you have the room with the hole from the start and don't need to modify it.

This is just an idea. I think there is no way of doing directly what you intend (make a hole in an existing geometry)